# Can I create (or simulate) AWS credential files in local directories?

Tags: amazon-web-services, configuration, command-line-interface

From the same (Mac) machine, I regularly bounce between absolutely unrelated projects.  Often, these projects have their own separately owned AWS instance (primarily Elastic Beanstalks)

I would like to be able to just `cd` into a project directory and have it know the credentials for that *specific* project, which I presume would require a `.aws` directory and the usual `credentials` and `config` files.

I cannot find anything in the documentation that explicitly allows this and named profiles aren't quite it, are they?

As a fallback, I could just write little scripts that change the directory and export the proper `AWS_PROFILE` value, but I wanted something that just works in context.

Am I asking for too much again? :-)

Comment: No vanilla way that I know of to make the credentials profile switch as you cd around your file system. It doesn't support a local `.aws/` folder to override `~/.aws/` unfortunately. But, a simple bash script could do it presumably (alias cd and optionally export AWS_PROFILE).

Comment: https://direnv.net/ is one option for setting environment variables when changing into a directory.  It will also unset the environment variables when exiting a directory.